# A tool to edit .dynsym symbols in ELF files

Tags: linux, software-development, command-line, elf

- [`objcopy(1)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/objcopy.1.html) can edit `.symtab` (among many other things), but not `.dynsym`.
- [`elfedit(1)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/elfedit.1.html) can modify small amount of header values
- [`patchelf(1)`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/patchelf.1.html) can modify other dynamic information (interpreter, libraries, soname), but not dynamic symbols.

But what tool should I use to edit dynamic symbol table, e.g. add new symbol or copy symbol from `.symtab`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[LIEF](https://lief.re//doc/latest/) is a tool for elf modification and is able to edit the dynamic symbol table:

```
# version 0.13.2-1
from lief import *

elf = ELF.parse("/bin/ls")

# make existing symbol dynamic
for symbol in elf.symbols:
    if symbol.name.startswith("snake"):
        elf.add_dynamic_symbol(symbol)

# make a single symbol dynamic
if sym := elf.get_symbol("python"):
    elf.add_dynamic_symbol(sym)

# add completely new symbol
sym = ELF.Symbol()
sym.name = "rattlesnake"
# make sure to use new reference that
# `add_*` functions return
sym = elf.add_dynamic_symbol(sym)
sym.type = ELF.SYMBOL_TYPES.FUNC
sym.binding = ELF.SYMBOL_BINDINGS.GLOBAL
for i, section in enumerate(elf.sections):
    if section.name == ".text":
        sym.shndx = i
        sym.value = section.virtual_address + 0x1337
        break

# save patched file
elf.write("patched")
```

We can confirm that the modification did take place:

```
$ readelf --dyn-syms -W patched | grep rattle
   120: 0000000000006357     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   12 rattlesnake
```

LIEF has c and c++ bindings as well, more documentation about those can be found on their website.

(I also used it recently to patch a build of gdb that did not export the proper symbols for libthread_db.so.1)